# How to fit text inside button when using layout_weight?

Tags: android

I am using a linear layout, with orientation =vertical, I have 3 buttons inside this linear layout with different weights(so that 3 of them fill the page horizontally). Because I want the button to look shorter, I set the height to 42 dip. It is looking fine in a big screen device, but when I test it on a very small screen device, half of the words in the middle button disappear because of the sizing issue. How do I solve this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/StatisticsButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewAllBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="42dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_for_statistic"
        android:text="View All"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_statistic"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewPartialBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="42dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_for_statistic"
        android:text="View partial record"                        //"View partial" displayed , I guess the screen is too "narrow" to display the "record"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_statistic"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewLeaveBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="42dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_for_statistic"
        android:text="Leave"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_statistic"
        android:textSize="17dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#0033d434" />

        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#aaa22f" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="#aaa22f" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using fixed density values for your button's size(ie; 42 dp). You really should stick to wrap_content or match_parent wherever possible to ensure that your assets/widgets will scale and fit accordingly across all devices. If you set the height and width of your button to wrap_content instead, you will find that it perfectly wraps text on multiple devices.

Comment: But the issue is the width being cut off, the height is fine though.

Comment: Exactly how much text are you trying to fit inside your button? Perhaps you can set your button width to wrap_content and programmatically set your text to the button?

Comment: I would like to fit the entire words "view partial record" inside the button, but only "view partial" is displayed on a smaller device

Comment: I see. Well it seems you'll have to make a bit of a compromise between wanting the button to be shorter than the other 2 or being able to display all of the text on all devices. I suggest you make the trade off and just go with the latter, setting the dimensions to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

When you use layout_weight the width of the controls is determined in ratio. In your case you have given 1, 1.3, 1 weights for your buttons. But your second button viewPartialBtn needs more width. You have to increase the width of it. You can try by giving layout_weight as 2, 5, 1 so that it takes the width required by the texts View all, View partial record and Leave.

In other words you tell the linearlayout to fit the width of your controls to be in ration 2:5:1.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your whole layout in a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).  Also, consider the screen sizes you are testing/targeting.  A couple of the default emulator sizes are so small that very few phones actually have those sizes: [Android Dashboard: Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).

EDIT:

Also consider providing alternate resources for different screen sizes.  You can adjust the text size based on the screen width (or other things).  See the [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) API guide.